# Is there a way to have a null default value for an HTML number input in a form instead of zero?

Tags: html, forms, input, null, numbers

I have a number input in an HTML form that looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group col">
  <label for="expLow1">Lower treshold (Exposure)</label>
  <input type="number" step="0.01" id="expLow1" name="expLow1" class="form-control" placeholder="ex: 2" >
</div>
```

The problem is that if the user leaves the field empty, the form returns a default value of zero.

I tried setting the value parameter to "null" or to "", but the form always return zero when the field is left empty.

is there a way to have a null value in return of a number input and not zero if the user leave the field empty?

Comment: why not use a regex to replace a single 0 with Null?

Comment: No. You cannot get a null from there. So you can do `const val = document.getElementById("expLow1").value || null` in JavaScript. On the server, you need to test for 0 or have a hidden field you update with the value or the string "null" if you need

Comment: The problem is that zero is a valid value for me, as well as "null", i can not replace later on all zeros with null, because i will lose information about the users that actually answered zero

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer, as mplungjan said it seems it is not possible to do what I wanted, so as i'm not very familiar with Javascript, I just created another field in the form, and depending on that value, later on I decide if my number input is Null or zero. Thanks again